# Why I get None when calling this method?

Tags: python, oop, recursion, binary-tree

I want to write method `mirror()` which creates and return binary tree where all left subtrees become right subtrees and vice versa. I tried to do this with recursion:

```
def mirror(self):
    if self.left == None and self.right == None:
        return
    elif self.left == None and self.right != None:
        t = self.right
        self.right = self.left
        self.left = t
        self.left.mirror()
    elif self.left != None and self.right == None:
        t = self.right
        self.right = self.left
        self.left = t
        self.right.mirror()
    else:
        t = self.right
        self.right = self.left
        self.left = t
        self.left.mirror()
        self.right.mirror()
```

But I get output `None`. Why, and how to fix it?

Comment: I see only one `return` in the entire function. How should it know what to return if you do not tell it?

Comment: And that one `return` `return`s `None`.  How are you expecting this function to `return` anything other than `None`?

Comment: It doesn't return a new reversed tree; it reverses the original tree in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current function swaps all the branches in-place; there's no particular need to return the tree, since you already have a reference to it if you managed to call the method in the first place. But if you want return such a reference anyway, you can:

```
def mirror(self):
    if self.left == None and self.right == None:
        pass
    elif self.left == None and self.right != None:
        t = self.right
        self.right = self.left
        self.left = t
        self.left.mirror()
    elif self.left != None and self.right == None:
        t = self.right
        self.right = self.left
        self.left = t
        self.right.mirror()
    else:
        t = self.right
        self.right = self.left
        self.left = t
        self.left.mirror()
        self.right.mirror()
    return self
```

or more simply:

```
def mirror(self):
    if self.left is not None:
        self.left.mirror()
    if self.right is not None:
        self.right.mirror()
    self.left, self.right = self.right, self.left
    return self
```

If, on the other hand, you want a *new* tree independent of the original tree, you need to construct one to return.

```
def mirror(self):
    new_tree = ...  # Whatever you do to create a root node from the root of self

    # If the child pointers aren't already None after creating the node
    new_tree.left = None
    new_tree.right = None

    if self.right is not None:
        new_tree.left = self.right.mirror()
    if self.left is not None:
        new_tree.right = self.left.mirror()

    return new_tree
```